# get mean form a column in a csv file on R

Tags: r

I am a very beginner user of R. I am taking the Coursera R programming course and I am stuck in a homework (the pollutant mean homework). The objective of the homework is to obtain means from columns in csv files. The files have four columns. We have 300+ files and each has 1000+ observations. Most of them Are NA. In the csv file I am working with there are only 117 numeric observations. I have been trying stuff like this:

```
cmydata1 <- read.csv("/Users/joshuavincent/Documents/specdata/001.csv")
```

Once I had cmydata1, I tried to get the mean of one of the columns, "nitrate" but I got this:

```
> mean(cmydata1, "nitrate")
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(cmydata1, "nitrate") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

To solve it I created a new list like this:

```
> cmydata2 <- list(na.omit(cmydata1))
> cmydata2[[1]]
```

The outcome is the cleaned matrix, no NA anymore

The column names are: "Date" "sulfate" "nitrate" and ID.

However, I still can't get the mean

```
> mean(cmydata2, "nitrate")
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(cmydata2, "nitrate") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I try to fix it, so I type... and get null

```
> colnames(cmydata2)
NULL
```

So, what could I fix to get the mean from that column? (Afterwards I think have to try loops and stuff to finish the homework, but I am going very baby steps towards it)

Note that might help: I have cmydata1 with a table icon in the autofill, while cmydata2 has some shapes, seems like an organigram icon.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is a rather simple question and you should probably just reference other questions that have been asked before. However, to try to answer, you reference columns in dataframes in two main ways listed out below (although there are other ways).

```
data(mtcars) #calling in some data that is stored in R already

##METHOD 1##
mean(mtcars$mpg,na.rm=T) #the 'na.rm=T' is to remove missing values before calculating the mean
20.09062

##METHOD 2##

mean(mtcars[,'mpg'],na.rm=T)
20.09062
```

Comment: I already did so. And tried all the solutions given for previous askers. Your solution did not work, it gave me the following: > mean(cmydata1, na.rm = T)
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: title
2: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: keyword
3: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: alias
4: In mean.default(cmydata1, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: I will keep working on it and come back if I have any new. Thanks!

Comment: No you did not try my solution. You are calling the entire dataset and trying to get the mean of that as opposed to a single column in your dataset. You need to try `mean(cmydata1$nitrate,na.rm=T)`

Comment: Oh my God, I am so lost... I will do this now and keep trying, thanks!

Comment: @NathalieCosta - just think of it as `data_set$column_name` or the other way to write it is `data_set[row_number,column_name]`.

Comment: Since this question is the top Google hit for *mean csv data R* maybe you should link to these "other questions that have been asked before"